# VueJS Toggle Prop Boolean Value Vis-a-vis a Computed Property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code for a component called navbar-base:

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <slot name="brand"></slot>
        <button class="button navbar-burger" v-if="burger" >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <slot name="menu-left"></slot>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-end">
          <slot name="menu-right"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    burger: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    hasBurger () {
      this.burger = true
      return this.burger
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to toggle on or off the `navbar-burger` as follows:

**Burger is visible (toggled on)**

```
<navbar-base class="is-info" hasBurger>

 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="brand">Brand name</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-left">Courses</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Videos</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Login</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Signup</a>

</navbar-base>
```

**Burger is NOT visible (toggled off)**

```
<navbar-base class="is-info">

 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="brand">Brand name</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-left">Courses</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Videos</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Login</a>
 <a href="#" class="navbar-item" slot="menu-right">Signup</a>

</navbar-base>
```

In other words, if I add `hasBurger` to the `<navbar-base>` tag then the burger code will be included.  Otherwise it won't.

The problem is that my code is not working -- and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.  The key was to actually NOT use a computed property at all.  This is the working code (in case anyone finds it helpful):

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <slot name="brand"></slot>
        <button class="button navbar-burger" v-if="hasBurger" >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <slot name="menu-left"></slot>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-end">
          <slot name="menu-right"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    hasBurger: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```